# PWA App - How can I check that app is running in kiosk mode? [ChromeOS]

Tags: google-chrome-os, kiosk-mode, chromebook

I had a Chromeos app and it was working fine. As Google now deprecated chromeos apps we are migrating to pwa app.

We were using the below code to check if the app is in kiosk mode and apply our logic only if it is in kiosk else we show the error dialogue.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(launchData) {
    launchData.isKioskSession; //true or false
});
```

**I could not find any similar way to do that using the PWA app in chromeOS for chrome books.**

Here is the official doc for launch data:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/app_runtime/